# Moving an Image Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I can get the image to turn but not to move, I think I'm close but have not been able to figure it out.

The CSS, body and window.onload function were given so I cannot change them. The assignment is to create the image then move the image depending on the key that is pressed.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> setTimeout </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    div#container {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 30%;     
    }

    div.bug {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 76px;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 2s;
      transition: transform 2s;
    }

    .up {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

   .down {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
   }

   .right {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
     transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

   .left {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
     transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
  </style>
  <script>
    // your code here

   function Bug () {
   //Assign local variables to be used within the function, call 
   //function to assign bug an id

   var bugDiv = document.getElementById("container");
   var bugId = getId();

  //call functions to display instructions and bug           
  displayBug();

  //public method to move bug only when certain keys are pressed. This 
  //function will move the showBug div created by the display
  //function.            

  this.moveBug = function (e) {
     if (window.event) {
     number = window.event.keyCode; 
      if (number == 106) {
        moveDown();
      }
      if (number == 107) { 
        moveUp();
      }
      if (number == 104) { 
        moveLeft();
      }
      if (number == 108) { 
        moveRight();
      }
    }
   } 

   function moveDown (){
     console.log("down");
     showBug.setAttribute("class", "down")
     showBug.style.top = parseInt(showBug.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
   }

   function moveUp () {
    console.log("up");
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "up");
    showBug.style.top = parseInt(showBug.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
   }

   function moveLeft() {
   console.log("left");
   showBug.setAttribute("class", "left");
   showBug.style.left = parseInt(showBug.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
   }

   function moveRight() {
   console.log("right");
   showBug.setAttribute("class", "right");
   showBug.style.left = parseInt(showBug.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
   }


  //private function to display bug in the orginal container div on the
  //page                  
  function displayBug() {     
    showBug = document.createElement("img");
    showBug.setAttribute("id", bugId);
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug"); 
    showBug.src = "/AdvJS/ladybug.png"; 
    showBug.style.marginTop = "200px"
    showBug.style.marginLeft = "100px"      
    bugDiv.appendChild(showBug);       
  }

  //private function to assign bug an id     
  function getId() {
    var bugs = document.querySelectorAll(".bug");
    if (bugs) {
      return bugs.length;
    }
    return 0;
  }    
}

window.onload = function() {
    var bug = new Bug("container");

    // j = 106 (down), k = 107 (up), h = 104 (left) , l = 108 (right)
    document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        bug.moveBug((typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode);
    }
};
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dropping off a block of code and asking why it doesnt work is off topic on stack overflow. please isolate the problematic code in a smaller simpler environment, and if it still doesnt work then post it back in your question.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'm sorry to post questions like this but after hours and hours of trying to figure it out it was either that or give up, do not want to give up - at least not yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. There were problems in your js.

- You've to set `top` and `left` while creating the element.
- While setting showBug.setAttribute("class", "down") class `bug` is getting removed. So the corresponding styles will not be applicable after that.

```js
$(function () {
    
   function Bug () {
   //Assign local variables to be used within the function, call 
   //function to assign bug an id

   var bugDiv = document.getElementById("container");
   var bugId = getId();

  //call functions to display instructions and bug           
  displayBug();

  //public method to move bug only when certain keys are pressed. This 
  //function will move the showBug div created by the display
  //function.            

  this.moveBug = function (e) {
      console.log(window.event.keyCode);
     if (window.event) {
     number = window.event.keyCode; 
      if (number == 106) {
        moveDown();
      }
      if (number == 107) { 
        moveUp();
      }
      if (number == 104) { 
        moveLeft();
      }
      if (number == 108) { 
        moveRight();
      }
    }
   } 

   function moveDown (){
     console.log("down");
     showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug down")
     showBug.style.top = parseInt(showBug.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
       console.log('top' + showBug);
   }

   function moveUp () {
    console.log("up");
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug up");
    showBug.style.top = parseInt(showBug.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
   }

   function moveLeft() {
   console.log("left");
   showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug left");
   showBug.style.left = parseInt(showBug.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
   }

   function moveRight() {
   console.log("right");
   showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug right");
   showBug.style.left = parseInt(showBug.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
   }


  //private function to display bug in the orginal container div on the
  //page                  
  function displayBug() {     
    showBug = document.createElement("img");
    showBug.setAttribute("id", bugId);
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug"); 
    showBug.src = "http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/70200/70297/70297_258_a-1b_s_lg.gif"; 
    showBug.style.top = "100px"
    showBug.style.left = "100px"      
    bugDiv.appendChild(showBug);       
  }

  //private function to assign bug an id     
  function getId() {
    var bugs = document.querySelectorAll(".bug");
    if (bugs) {
      return bugs.length;
    }
    return 0;
  }    
}

    var bug = new Bug("container");

    $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
 
        bug.moveBug((typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode);

    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    div#container {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 30%;  
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    }

    div .bug {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 76px;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 2s;
      transition: transform 2s;
    }

 .up {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

   .down {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
   }

   .right {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

   .left {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, position of object that you want to move needs to be in `position: relative`, second use `marginTop`, `marginLeft` insted of `top` and `left`, etc.

Moving object UP: `showBug.style.marginTop = parseInt(showBug.style.marginTop) - 10 + 'px'`, same way for left.

Working example: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8uLuqzv6/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Set `position` programmatically in the `displayBug()` function, to give an origin:

```
showBug.style.position = "absolute";
showBug.style.left = "10px";
showBug.style.right = "10px";
showBug.style.top = "10px";
showBug.style.bottom = "auto";
```

Example below, using your buttons h, j, k, l to move (and you have to focus the window first):

```js
function Bug() {
  //Assign local variables to be used within the function, call 
  //function to assign bug an id

  var bugDiv = document.getElementById("container");
  var bugId = getId();

  //call functions to display instructions and bug           
  displayBug();

  //public method to move bug only when certain keys are pressed. This 
  //function will move the showBug div created by the display
  //function.            

  this.moveBug = function(e) {
    if (window.event) {
      number = window.event.keyCode;
      if (number == 106) {
        moveDown();
      }
      if (number == 107) {
        moveUp();
      }
      if (number == 104) {
        moveLeft();
      }
      if (number == 108) {
        moveRight();
      }
    }
  }

  function moveDown() {
    console.log("down");
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug down")
    showBug.style.top = parseInt(showBug.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
  }

  function moveUp() {
    console.log("up");
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug up");
    showBug.style.top = parseInt(showBug.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
  }

  function moveLeft() {
    console.log("left");
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug left");
    showBug.style.left = parseInt(showBug.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
  }

  function moveRight() {
    console.log("right");
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug right");
    showBug.style.left = parseInt(showBug.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
  }


  //private function to display bug in the orginal container div on the
  //page                  
  function displayBug() {
    showBug = document.createElement("img");
    showBug.setAttribute("id", bugId);
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug");
    showBug.src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jen/animal/32/Lady-bug-icon.png";
    showBug.style.marginTop = "20px";
    showBug.style.marginLeft = "20px";
    showBug.style.position = "absolute";
    showBug.style.left = "10px";
    showBug.style.right = "10px";
    showBug.style.top = "10px";
    showBug.style.bottom = "auto";
    bugDiv.appendChild(showBug);
  }

  //private function to assign bug an id     
  function getId() {
    var bugs = document.querySelectorAll(".bug");
    if (bugs) {
      return bugs.length;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var bug = new Bug("container");

  // j = 106 (down), k = 107 (up), h = 104 (left) , l = 108 (right)
  document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    bug.moveBug((typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode);
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
}
.bug {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 2s;
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.up {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.right {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.left {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey [TRogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4293631/trogers), 
this is a nice exercise to learn the basics of JavaScript and CSS... But it is not a good question for stackoverflow. Some guys won't be amused :) 
But i'm in a good mood so i did a snippet for you. If you dare to cheat yourself, you can find a possible solving for your problem there.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> setTimeout </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    div#container {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 30%;     
    }

    div.bug {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 76px;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 2s;
      transition: transform 2s;
    }

    .up {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

   .down {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
   }

   .right {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
     transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

   .left {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
     transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
  </style>
  <script>
    // your code here

   function Bug () {
   //Assign local variables to be used within the function, call 
   //function to assign bug an id

   var bugDiv = document.getElementById("container");
   var bugId = getId();

  //call functions to display instructions and bug           
  displayBug();

  //public method to move bug only when certain keys are pressed. This 
  //function will move the showBug div created by the display
  //function.            

  this.moveBug = function (e) {
    console.log('event',e)
      
      if (e === 106) {
        moveDown();
      }
      else if (e === 107) { 
        moveUp();
      }
      else if (e === 104) { 
        moveLeft();
      }
      else if (e === 108) { 
        console.log('moving right');
        moveRight();
      }else {
        console.log('unknown command!');
      }
    
   } 

   function moveDown (){
     console.log("down");
     showBug.setAttribute("class", "down")
     showBug.style.marginTop = parseInt(showBug.style.marginTop) + 5 + 'px';
   }

   function moveUp () {
    console.log("up");
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "up");
    showBug.style.marginTop = parseInt(showBug.style.marginTop) - 5 + 'px';
   }

   function moveLeft() {
   console.log("left");
   showBug.setAttribute("class", "left");
   showBug.style.marginLeft = parseInt(showBug.style.marginLeft) - 5 + 'px';
   }

   function moveRight() {
   console.log("right yeaahhh");
   showBug.setAttribute("class", "right");
   showBug.style.marginLeft = parseInt(showBug.style.marginLeft) + 5 + 'px';
   }


  //private function to display bug in the orginal container div on the
  //page                  
  function displayBug() {     
    showBug = document.createElement("img");
    showBug.setAttribute("id", bugId);
    showBug.setAttribute("class", "bug"); 
    showBug.src = "/AdvJS/ladybug.png"; 
    showBug.style.marginTop = "200px"
    showBug.style.marginLeft = "100px"      
    bugDiv.appendChild(showBug);       
  }

  //private function to assign bug an id     
  function getId() {
    var bugs = document.querySelectorAll(".bug");
    if (bugs) {
      return bugs.length;
    }
    return 0;
  }    
}

window.onload = function() {
    var bug = new Bug("container");

    // j = 106 (down), k = 107 (up), h = 104 (left) , l = 108 (right)
    document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        bug.moveBug((typeof e.which === "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode);
    }
};
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice: It's not the best way, just made it in a few minutes to give you a hint. Please try to solve it a better way for a better understanding! Good luck and have fun! :)